# Create custom action for Views Bulk Operations

Tags: nodes

I'm trying to add some custom actions to my Views Bulk Operations, but for some reason, they don't appear in the list.
i want to add custom button to user can apply it and node DATE update to today...

This is my code (so I guess this is a working code...)

```
    /**
 * Implements hook_action_info().
 */
function custom_action_info() {
  return array(
    'custom_action_callback_name' => array(
      'type' => 'entity', // Can be file, term, user, etc.
      'label' => t('Your label'),
      'configurable' => FALSE, // Doesn't need config form
      'behavior' => array('view_property'), // Uses view access rights
      'triggers' => array('any'), // Works always
    ),
  );
}
/**
 * Add action callback where you perform the action. 
 */
function custom_action_callback_name($entity, $context) {

  // I DONT KNOW .....................

}
```

Comment: You mean it doesn't appear in the list of actions (buttons) when you visit the view page/block?

Comment: Change this `'type' => 'entity'` with an actual entity like comment, taxonomy , node, user etc and then retry

Answer (score 1):

I believe your type should not be `entity` but the actual entity type you want to use, like `node`. Then it should show up on nodes.

Also VBO requires no triggers to be defined, unless you want the action to be triggered via the action module as well. For just VBO this can be an empty array.
I have no idea what behavior is, never used it.

See an example of VBO with a form here: [Add multiple friends at once with user relationships](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194433)